# Can't use \s as an escape character?

Tags: python, string, syntax

I can use other escape characters without any problem but my atom text editor and python itself doesn't see it as an escape character but as a normal character.

```
print '\s', test_line
```

just writes

```
\stesting_bot1
```

How can I make it so that the editor and python will see this as an escape character and as space ?

Comment: `\s` is not an escape sequence in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\s` isn't an escape sequence in Python. `\t`, `\n`, `\r` etc are (see [the Python lexical analysis docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)) but non-special characters will not be interpreted as anything special, hence your `\s` appearing literally.

However, `\s` does means space in [regular expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) of course...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification \s was categorized as 'space' so I was confused as to why it did not work as such.

Comment: I see - updated to reflect the possible source of confusion..

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be confusing a `regex` with a `string`. For a normal string, you just need to use the space character to print it:

```
print(' testing_bot1')
```

`\s` is not an escape sequence, so it will be interpreted as just backslash + "s".

Comment: Ah I see I wanted to use a little more elegant way for space but I guess I was just being stubborn. Thanks but I wonder why \s was categorized as an escape character in tutorialspoint.

Comment: @BuğraCoşkun that tells more about the quality of tutorialspoint, or, rather lack thereof

Comment: @BuğraCoşkun: An escape character is a character that escapes a symbol. You are using some very unclear terminology. Use official documentation if it is available.

Comment: @BuğraCoşkun In my opinion, there is no better, clearer, or more elegant representation of a space than a space ;)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are right I did use a very vague and maybe a wrong terminology because I didn't know much about the topic. Well asking the right question is half of the answer. But most of the time we don't know what we don't know. Seems like I'm going off topic here comments section is not meant to be used as such so I will just quiet down now. Thanks everyone.